# Dependencies Error

Tags: android, dependencies, google-play-services

I am having the following error in my project. I have tried many solution but none worked for me. I am proviging the screenshots of project kindly help me in solving this problem.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

Please Solve my this problem..

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

1.Right click your project
2.Select -> properties
3.Select -> Java Build Path
4.Select -> Libraries
5.Select -> Google play services lib.jar file 
6.Select -> Remove
7.Select -> Add External JARS
8.Select -> New google paly service
9.Select -> Order and Export 
10.Click -> Select All
11.Click -> ok
12.Select -> Clean your projects 
13.finished

**Second screen shot**
1.Click Google play service.jar file
2.Remove your jar file
3. Add new Google play service.jar file

your problem solve

Comment: Tried, but didn't worked. now problem in .xml file.. error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.solutionproviders.XXXXXXX'

Answer (score 0):

As the second screenshot suggests, the library for google play services (a .jar file) is missing. You need to delete that dependency, and add it by hand (I guess you imported this project from somewhere else). Make sure in your Android SDK manager you download the Google Play Services Library, then in eclipse you can import it by going to your Android SDK folder and import the jar file, the path should be like this ..\Android SDK\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar

Update:
The error you are getting is not related to the library already, it's a different error, there is no size value for the AdView (missing or it was somewhere in the app inserted and the reference is missing).

I guess you talk about this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.solutionproviders.rapsongs&hl=en

Comment: Yes I am talking about the same application, its one of mine developed application. (But how did you get to know about that? I haven't mentioned any this related to app, hmm ??) And I actully didn't get you, what are you suggesting me?

Comment: I was suggesting a fix for the library error. Then I read your comment about the XML error, and mentioned that this is already another issue, not related to the previous one, there was a value in XML for the adSize property (maybe referenced somewhere else), and probably is missing right now. Check here for possible values to be used https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html